# If we assume an ideal wire, does electron lose its potential as it travels in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, field-theory

A battery maintains a constant potential difference across its ends. If we connect the ends of the battery using an ideal(resistance=0) wire, an electric field is generated in the wire that carries the charges from the high potential to the low potential. So, according to the statement that electric potential decreases in the direction of the electric field, does that mean that as the charges travel in the wire, their potential decreases at every point?

Comment: I just don’t get how the charges in a wire can remain at the same potential if they are moving in the direction of the electric field. They must lose potential slowly, right?

Comment: You are asking for precisely the infinite case, whereby the maths break down. The potential is well-defined in the limit, and yes, it will decrease slowly, but the current, the electric field, and so forth, explode to infinity. In the end the battery fails to keep up and the potential becomes constant over the wire, i.e. the battery fails to maintain the potential difference. Real batteries always fail to maintain the potential difference either, when a non-zero current flows.

Answer (score 0):

> If we connect the ends of the battery using an ideal(resistance=0) wire, an electric field is generated in the wire that carries the charges from the high potential to the low potential.

*Current* would move from high potential to low potential (by definition). Electrons would move in the opposite direction.

> does that mean that as the charges travel in the wire, their potential decreases at every point?

As electron travels in the wire, potential at the position of the electron increases.

So a piece of wire does not have the same potential everywhere.

Zero resistance wire means total electric field has to vanish in the wire. So the conservative electric field due to the battery has to be cancelled by some other contribution to total electric field. This other contribution is due to induced electric field, due to accelerated current in the wire. So this way, as long as current changes in time, it is possible that both 1) potential changes along the wire, and 2) net electric field in the wire is zero.

This is all very theoretical. Real wire with current changing in time always has some resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reason about an impossible ideal. Real batteries don't maintain a constant potential. Superconductors only carry limited current.

I strongly recommend that you try it. Get an alkaline battery and a wire, connect them in a circuit, and see what happens. Don't do this with lithium, though, as fire or explosion are likely. For extra insight, measure the potential differences between various points with a voltmeter.

The abstractions you're manipulating are not physics: they compose an (impossible) physical model. It is important to understand real, concrete physics to understand how to apply them. Sadly, most textbooks won't tell you this.